# Nosetest initialisation error

Tags: python, nosetests, unit-testing

calling `nosetests` gives me the following:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: TypeError (__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sheena/WORK/CriticalID/workspace/flow_env2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 519, in makeTest
    return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
  File "/home/sheena/WORK/CriticalID/workspace/flow_env2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 578, in _makeTest
    return MethodTestCase(obj)
  File "/home/sheena/WORK/CriticalID/workspace/flow_env2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/case.py", line 345, in __init__
    self.inst = self.cls()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

as well as some other stuff.

My directory structure looks like:

```
MyStuff
   ./__init__.py
   ./tests
        ./some_tests.py
        ./other_tests.py
        ./ ... lots more
        ./a_useful_group_of_tests
           ./more_tests.py
           ./tasty_tests.py
           ./ ...lots more
   ./other_files_and_directories
```

Now there are a lot of tests in a lot of files and this error gives me no indication of where in my code the error came from. Any ideas about how I can find it? The best I can come up with so far is to get rid of all the test files and then put them back one by one but that is not exactly ideal.

Comment: Do any of your test cases have non-default constructors? i.e. `__init__(self, some_param)`

Comment: You can run individual tests by specifying the filename after the `nosetests` command. I also think you can run `nosetests` per subdirectory, as it recurses just that subdirectory. That should help limit the files you're testing as well.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the verbosity of nose: `-vv` and variants. Perhaps nose will tell you enough then to deduce the bad file.

Comment: @PeterWood: everything is inheriting from unittest.TestCase. I'm not doing anything to the test constructors

Comment: @Evert: Thanks. I've located the file causing the problems. I'll add more detail to my question in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution:**

remove import statements from the top of the script.

**Why:**

After locating the test file giving me issues I executed `nosetests` with the `-vv` option as per Evert's suggestion. It turned out that the error message wasn't coming from any specific test. Ie, the tests were running as expected, those errors were just tagged onto the output. The output looked something like:

```
Failure: TypeError (__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)) ... ERROR
Failure: TypeError (__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)) ... ERROR
...
test_clear_instructions (the_calculator2.tests.model_tests.workflow_tests.Workflow_tests) ... 
...all my tests follow
```

The only things not in test cases were import statements. So I just moved them to where they were used.

**But why would this happen? Bonus points to anyone who knows**

again, I dont feel like reading through reams of code to find the answer

---

Illustrative code:

```
from my.stuff import goodies    #<----------Error from this line

class My_tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        do stuff
    def test_two(self):
        do other stuff
```

No error in this code:

```
class My_tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        from my.stuff import goodies
        do stuff
    def test_two(self):
        from my.stuff import goodies
        do other stuff
```

Comment: Since you ask a new question, you could better update your current question with this solution, *and* the new question (but don't overwrite the old one, just add to it), *or* ask a completely new question. Otherwise you get answers that answer an *answer* instead of the question asked.

Comment: You should show a minimal test where the problem occurs though, for people to be able to answer this.

Comment: @Evert: My original q is how to solve the problem I faced. The problem is solved, thus the question answered. If anyone has a better answer than mine (one that doesn't just fix things but says what is actually going on) I will be happy to mark it as correct and probably up-vote it too because this stuff is just plain weird. What I'm asking for here is a more useful version of my own correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The usual reason for this is that you are using a class in one of those tests that is not imported in it or that has broken imports in it. Or otherwise have an individually broken test or imported class that when initialised with the other tests via the global nose test case runner environment is OK due for example to the missing import being imported in another test. 
But on initial loading of the test class or individual loading - it would raise a not found or other error. But nose doesnt make that very clear although it is probably showing the initialisation error for the class.

So using your sample code in the test environment something in 'goodies' is not being passed an argument at module initialisation time, that is required for it to be initialized correctly. But gets it if initialized later on in the tests.

Alternatively you have a method accidentally called test_something in a class that isn't meant to be a test class (eg. somewhere in goodies or a class used by it) and nose finds and initialises it without the required parameters.

You can try going through the imports one by one putting them back to the module level - then initialising the problem class on the python shell to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

So I spent way too much time on this issue and want to give back.

If you run nosetests with `--with-xunit` you'll notice that the test that the failure is booked under the path `nose.failure.Failure.runTest`. If you try to run that test, it will say it doesn't exist. Something weird is going on here.

Interestingly if you run it under `--collect-only --verbose` you'll get `Failure: TypeError (__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)) ... ok`, so something is first being recognized as a test when it probably shouldn't, and second it fails immediately. Evily, the two packages adjacent to the failing test both pass so even figuring out which file is failing is not straightforward.

As it turns out, there's a non-test file someone created that had `test` in its name. Nose tried to interpret it as as test and hence the error.

Sadly I had to manually run every package to figure this out. One way you can do this is to `find /path/to/package -name "*test*.py` and then grep for anything that doesn't live in a tests directory.

Comment: I have encountered this case twice, where it runs a file with `test` prefix, which doesn't contain any tests. I decorate the classes in these files with `@nottest`, and that solves the problem.